# When commandType is text (not stored procedure), how to use output parameter?

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, npgsql

When commandType is text (not stored procedure), how can i use output parameter?

With this sample, I got this error.
: System.Exception: 'Parameter 'PARAM' referenced in SQL but is an out-only parameter'

```
        using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString)) {
            connection.Open();

            var dbCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
            dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            dbCommand.CommandText = @"
                SELECT COLUMN_A into @PARAM
                FROM TABLE_A 
                ORDER BY COLUMN_A DESC 
                LIMIT 1;
            ";

            var param = new NpgsqlParameter("PARAM", -1);
            param.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
            dbCommand.Parameters.Add(param);

            dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); // error!

            var result = dbCommand.Parameters["PARAM"];
        }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: From a quick search it looks like MySQL might have a similar issue: https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/231. The recommendation there is to do a SELECT and then use ExecuteScalar or ExecuteReader to get the returned value.

Comment: I'm not sure how to make the code work like you're trying, but typically a `SELECT ... INTO` query would be used when you're expecting a scalar result.  It looks like you're expecting a set here, which is commonly processed using a reader, like in this page: http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/npgsql_dotnet